# How to change the background image accordingly to the React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, background-image

I want to have different background images in different components

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";


// SCREENS
import Login from './containers/Login';
import Register from './containers/Register';
import LandingPage from './containers/LandingPage';

// STYLE
import './styles/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**index.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #282c34;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

**LandingPage.js (example of a component that I want to change the background image but it renders only the background color defined in the index.css file)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';

import '../styles/Animations.css';
import "../styles/LandingPage.css";

class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="back center animate-opacity">
        <Logo/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

**This is the LandingPage.css. When I try to apply the css tag "background-image" it only covers like 80% of the total height of the screen.**

```
.back{ 
    background-image: url("../assets/background/jj1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

**Animations.css**

```
.animate-fading{animation:fading 10s infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
.animate-opacity{animation:opac 0.8s}@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
.animate-top{position:relative;animation:animatetop 1s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-60px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
.animate-left{position:relative;animation:animateleft 0.4s}@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-20px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
.animate-right{position:relative;animation:animateright 0.4s}@keyframes animateright{from{right:-20px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
.animate-bottom{position:relative;animation:animatebottom 2s}@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-50px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}}
```

Comment: Is the issue that it covers only 80% or that it's not changing?

Comment: @niiapa It covers only 80%... The image appears but does not cover the entire screen. Maybe this is the wrong way...

Comment: Could you post what's in the two css files you imported in Landing Page?
And also your App component?

Comment: @niiapa just added!